# Square and Summing a List

Tags: python, list

I'm working on the problem below, but I'm a little stuck on how to set up my main function:

Write a program that will accept a list of numbers from the user. Write and test two functions to meet the following specifications:

> squareEach(nums), nums is a list of numbers, returns a list of the square of each number in the list
>
> sumList(nums), nums is a list of numbers, returns the sum of the numbers in the list
>
> Print the original list, the list of squared values and the sum of the list.

```
#import reduce function
from functools import reduce

def numbers(n):
    numbers = []

    data = input("Enter a number or press Enter to quit: ")

    while True: 
        #request input from user
        data = input("Enter a number or press Enter to quit: ")

        #set up the termination condition    
        if data == "":
            break

#define square function
def SquareEach(numbers):
    return map(lambda x: x**2, numbers)

#define sum function
def SumList(numbers):
    return map(lambda x, y: x + y, numbers)

#main program start
def main(): 

#main program end
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write each function as follows

Square each element within a list comprehension

```
def sqauareEach(nums):
    return [num**2 for num in nums]
```

Simply use the built-in `sum` function

```
def sumList(nums):
    return sum(nums)
```

If you had to write the second function "manually" without using the built in, you could use a `for` loop

```
def sumList(nums):
    total = 0
    for num in nums:
        total += num
    return total
```

To enter a list of numbers

```
def getInputs():
    entry = input('Enter values delimeted by space: ')
    return [int(i) for i in entry.split()]
```

Finally `main` would just be

```
def main():
    nums = getInputs()
    squares = squareEach(nums)
    total = sumList(nums)
```

Then you could add some `print` statements to output those values if you wanted.